# What is 'az acr build' with a local context doing under the hood?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

I was trying to do this in Pulumi where I had a local Dockerfile and wanted it to be sent to build the same as the command 'az acr build' sadly it kept erroring as it wanted a full url.
I did some digging but I can't quite figure it out. I'm not a developer as such, just a dabbler.
what is az acr build doing under the hood and can this be replicated using the APIs ?

This is the build command
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/acr/build.py

And it also calls this as part of it
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_archive_utils.py

What it seems to be doing is calling the api to get a storage account and sas that lives behind the ACR and then Tar/gzip and uploading to it and then referencing it?
But I can't find any documented behaviour for that for ACR. Like how do you see that zip and remove it once it's built. That kind of thing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/registries%20(tasks)/get-build-source-upload-url

If anyone can explain what's going on there that would be great thanks.

Comment: its not quite clear what your actual question is. You already described the behavior. `az acr build` will package up your local files, upload them and then the service will build and push your docker image. Thats all it does.

Comment: @silent that’s fair I guess.   I suppose I’m wondering what this blob storage part is as I can’t find any api info about it beyond getting the upload uri. Like if I was replicating this in Pulumi or rest would it have just a separate upload blob step ? Or is there something I can put into the REST to do the upload  ?

Comment: I still wonder what you actually want to achieve? You do not want to use the az CLI but start the build via a REST call?

Comment: @silent yes I want to do the same thing in Pulumi but also understand the REST involved. Like after it upload the tar. If it doesn’t get deleted what happens to it.  Does it just sit there. It’s very opaque what’s happening

Comment: Did you try to create an acr task or an acr quick task with pulumi? Can you share the code you used from pulumi? if looking at a simple az acr task then it should be fairly straight forward - see; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-overview#task-scenarios
 
 AND  https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/containerregistry/task/#tasks_create_quicktask

Comment: @KedMardemootoo sure I can do. Basically I have made them up and point them to a git repo source and it’s fine. But if I try to point it just to the local path it breaks.   Hence me wondering how az cli does it for build and seeing that it seems to upload to some secret blob space.  I’ll have to switch to computer but appreciate all the attention so far from everyone thank you